# C - How do you store a string with variables in it within an array?

Tags: c, string

Because I know that

```
char array[STRING_ELEMENTS + 1][MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];

/*just for the first element*/
array[0] == ("this number: %d, and that number: %d\n", a, b);
```

probably makes me look disgusting. I would have no clue how else to do this though.

Comment: You mean the problem that you have to use MAX_STRING_LENGTH?

Comment: You title is confusing .

Comment: @ameyCU sorry I'm very new to this. What do you suggest I name it to?

Comment: @Superlokkus I don't understand?

Comment: @Laefica The problem is: If your string gets longer than MAX_STRING_LENGTH because of the variables, `snprintf ` which you must use for a safe program, will truncate you string.

Comment: @Superlokkus Ah, I'll look out for that in the future. For now, my assignment specification allows me to assume that will never happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign a string like this in C, but you can use [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
snprintf(array[0], MAX_STRING_LENGTH, "this number: %d, and that number: %d\n", a, b);
```

(don't forget to `#include <stdio.h>` somewhere near the top of your program.)

Comment: and `#include <stdio.h>` (for `snprintf(3)` function) also.